# How to get Locale-independent modification date batch

Tags: batch, locale, date-modified

**I need to get the modification date of a file** stored in a variable like this: `YearMonthDayHourMinute`. So `01/21/2019 9:12 AM` would be `201901210912`. What I will be doing is comparing files to see which is newer, so it needs to be like this in 24 hour format. I was initially going to get it with this command: `for %? IN ("%cd%\out.txt") do (echo %~t?)` and use the for loop to split the output apart, **but I was wondering if the modification date from a for loop is locale dependent** like `%date%`? If it is, is there a way to check which type of format it is under, or is there a way to get a non-locale dependent modification date?

*This is related to [Why wont this function's variables set? Batch Code](https://superuser.com/questions/1396791/why-wont-this-functions-variables-set-batch-code) but I don't see how solving one would necessarily alter the other one, so I'm keeping them as separate questions.*

Comment: Hi Mark - How about `wmic datafile where name="C:\\folder\\folder\\File.txt" get LastModified /format:list` or something like that. I think you do not want AM/PM format though and you want `00-24` format on the `YYYYMMDDhhmm` string format. Maybe this can work for you and you can iterate loop the file with a `FOR /R` loop for something for the file name and path. Just a quick idea for you just in case.

Comment: `No Instance(s) Available.` I was able to convert AM/PM into a number (AM is 1, PM is 2) and put it before the time so it still applies as a larger number.

Comment: For some reason, the WMIC needs to use two backslashes like it needs to escape the character or whatever. Be sure the full file path uses two forward slashes between the folder paths otherwise, you will need to `cd /d` to the dir and then specify the file name only I think.

Comment: Are you strictly limited to batch scripts? Windows also comes with PowerShell, JScript, VBScript.

Comment: I was already in the same directory of the file, I'll try using the full path with double quotes.

I can't use PowerShell for security reasons, but JScript and VBScript would be fine.

Comment: The wmic command worked well. I can probably manipulate a Path string to replace ` \ ` with ` \\ ` so it can handle it, then parse it into that command.

Comment: I'm actually getting the error `C:\\Users\\theBATeam\\CMDS.bat - Invalid alias verb. ` Any ideas as to what that means? My script is: https://pastebin.com/raw/qvLwygB3

Comment: I never knew about that.... I think a fix is mentioned [here using call per the rojo answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908430/issue-with-wmic-and-and-verb) but you could also consider just piping the command output to a file and then reading the content of the file to set as the variable and then delete the file. Not sure how many files or if the total overhead would be too much but that's another quick thought.

Comment: the for loop isn't running when I do that. It successfully outputs it into a file but: `For /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%a in (out.temp) do set %~2=%%b` does nothing. If I make it `For /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%a in (out.temp) do echo hello` it never echos hello.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> set _ForString=%~1
> set _ForString=!_ForString:\=\\!
> For /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%a in ('wmic datafile where name="!_ForString!" get LastModified /format:list') do (
>   echo %%a    %%b
>   set %~2=%%b
> )
>
> Rem %1 is set to C:\Users\%username%\CMDS.bat
> ```
>
> I'm actually getting the error `C:\\Users\\theBATeam\\CMDS.bat - Invalid alias verb`.

There are two problems in the above code snippet:

- in `name="!_ForString!"`: you need to [escape the *equals sign*](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters) as `name^="!_ForString!"`;
- parsing `wmic` output in a `FOR /F` loop (explained below).

`:ParseWmicDatafile` subroutine in the following *commented* `.bat` script should do the job:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

call :ParseWmicDatafile "%~f0" LastModified
REM show all variables prefixed with an underscore
set _

goto :eof

:ParseWmicDatafile
REM inputs (by value): %1 is a fully qualified file name 
REM                    %2 is a valid "wmic datafile" property name

REM outputs (by reference): _%~2 is a variable name drawn from supplied %2: 
REM                              property name prefixed with an underscore
REM                         _ForString

  REM remove residuary variable _%~2 (if present)
  if defined _%~2 set "_%~2="
  set "_ForString=%~1"
  set "_ForString=%_ForString:\=\\%"
  for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in (
      'wmic datafile where name^="%_ForString%" get %~2 /format:list'
    ) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~B") do (
        echo %%A    %%b
        set "_%~2=%%b"
    )
goto :eof
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%A` to retrieve the `LastModified` property *name* (`%%A`) and *value* (`%%B`);
- `%%b` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned; `wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`<CR><CR><LF>`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`<CR><LF>`).

See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SU\1396664.bat
LastModified    20190201220347.477320+060
_ForString=D:\\bat\\SU\\1396664.bat
_LastModified=20190201220347.477320+060

==>
```